# Getting id of poll from WP database

Tags: php, database, wpdb, poll

So I have a php statement:

`$latest_pollsid` that contains a number which increases by 1 every time a specific form is submitted. I am reading this statement into several functions and for one of these functions I would like it to capture the value at the current time and not update. Essentially I want it to read the statement when the function runs, grab the number, and then display that without it changing in the future even when the value of the statement itself changes. Is there a way to do this with PHP?

---

The Scenario:

I am creating a post in the background when the user creates a new poll which embeds the poll they have just made with a shortcode. The shortcode uses the latest poll generally meaning that if I create a poll now and create a poll tomorrow, tomorrow both posts will show tomorrows poll. Todays post won't show today's poll.

Code used to create the background post:

```
function programmatically_create_post() {

    // Initialize the page ID to -1. This indicates no action has been taken.
    $post_id = -1;

    // Setup the author, slug, and title for the post
    $author_id = 1;
    $slug = 'example-post';
    $title = 'My Example Background Post';

    // If the page doesn't already exist, then create it
    if( null == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {

        // Set the post ID so that we know the post was created successfully
        $pollq_question = wp_kses_post( trim( $_POST['pollq_question'] ) );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status'    =>  'open',
                'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
                'post_name'         =>  $slug,
                'post_title'        =>  $pollq_question,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'         =>  'post',
                'post_content'      =>  '[poll id="' . $latest_pollid . '"]'
            )
        );

    // Otherwise, we'll stop
    } else {

            // Arbitrarily use -2 to indicate that the page with the title already exists
            $post_id = -2;

    } // end if

} // end programmatically_create_post
add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'programmatically_create_post' );
```

---

PHP FUNCTION CODE:

```
function polls_latest_id() {
    global $wpdb;
    $poll_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT pollq_id FROM $wpdb->pollsq WHERE pollq_active = 1 ORDER BY pollq_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1");
    return intval($poll_id);
}
```

MANAGE POLLS CODE

This page manages to list all of the polls with the correct id's but without knowing PHP very well I am struggling to interpret this:

```
echo "<tr id=\"poll-$poll_id\" $style>\n";
                    echo '<td><strong>'.number_format_i18n($poll_id).'</strong></td>'."\n";
                    echo '<td>';
                    if($current_poll > 0) {
                        if($current_poll == $poll_id) {
                            echo '<strong>'.__('Displayed:', 'wp-polls').'</strong> ';
                        }
                    } elseif($current_poll == 0) {
                        if($poll_id == $latest_poll) {
                            echo '<strong>'.__('Displayed:', 'wp-polls').'</strong> ';
                        }
                    } else if(in_array($poll_id, $multiple_polls)) {
                            echo '<strong>'.__('Displayed:', 'wp-polls').'</strong> ';
                    }
```

Comment: You can't save data in PHP at all. You have to write to a file (generally a bad idea) or save to the database. Are you hacking somebody else's plugin?

Comment: @s_ha_dum the plugin is installed on my site but yes I am trying to modify it so that it shows the latest poll at time of creation and not just in general. Are there any other options to get the latest id at time of creation?

Comment: "latest poll at time of creation" -- no idea what that means

Comment: Ok so it is a poll plugin which lets users make polls. I am creating a post in the background when the user creates a new poll which embeds the poll they have just made with a shortcode. The shortcode uses the latest poll  generally meaning that if I create a poll now and create a poll tomorrow, tomorrow both posts will show tomorrows poll. Todays post won't show today's poll. I know it's not a very good explanation but it's quite hard to put into words :P

Comment: I thought this was going to be off topic but given that "I am creating a post in the background when the user creates a new poll which embeds the poll they have just made with a shortcode" it should be ok. Post the code that creates the post mentioned in that sentence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33329/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-s-ha-dum).

Comment: You should save the value of $latest_pollid for each post as an item of metadata for the post, using a [Custom Field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Comment: @Joel Thanks I will take a look at that. Can these inputs be overwritten or will another entry be created?

Comment: @Joel also would I load that in to the post or what? Thx

Comment: Yes, you would use set_post_metadata() when you first save the post, and then get_post_metadata() when you load the post.

Comment: @Joel I have started creating a custom field but am unsure about how to load the $latest_pollid would you care to take a look? http://i.imgur.com/T4mU0hU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I spotted is that you aren't setting `$latest_pollid` but you are nonetheless trying to use that as the poll id. You should have something like: `$latest_pollid = polls_latest_id();` before that line in order to set the value.

There are big problems with what you are doing though. Hooking to `after_setup_theme` means that your code runs on every page load. You are restricting most of it to the page titled 'My Example Background Post' but I still suspect you are getting a disconnect between the quiz and the post you are creating. I don't know how to solve this unless the quiz plugin has a hook you can use, or perhaps the `$_POST` data has information that could be relevant.

Comment: by declaring `$latest_pollid = polls_latest_id();` within the function and by altering the post content code to this `'post_content'      =>  '[poll id=' . $latest_pollid . ']'` It is now returning a number and working perfectly.